# Criando um conjunto de variaveis no PHP

Tags: php

Sou novato em PHP, e estou com algumas duvidas. Notei que quando as variáveis são criadas, os tipos não são especificados.

Sendo assim:

- como faço para criar as variáveis do tipo short int, int e char? Ele cria o tipo de variável na inicialização da mesma?
- e como eu poderia verificar o tamanho da varivel em bytes?
- Além disso, é possivel criar um conjunto de variáveis no PHP, e a partir de um identificar desse conjunto, atribuir valores a essas variáveis?

Comment: Dá um vista de olhos em http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: Não entendi ....

Comment: Acho que "Vista de olhos" em Portugual é "dar uma olhada" no Nrasil

Comment: Nao entendi o conteudo do link passado ... Não consegui relacionar com minha pergunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O PHP é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca. Isso significa que não é necessário definir um tipo para a variável.

Então é como você disse:

> ele cria o tipo da variável na inicialização da mesma

Exemplo:

```
 $int = 1;

 $float = 1.44;

 $string = 'stackoverflow';

 $boolean = false;

 $array = array();

 $object = new stdClass;
```

Você pode testar os tipos dessas variáveis através de funções como `is_string`, `is_float`, `is_int` e `is_boolean`.

É possível também obter o nome do tipo de variável através da função `gettype`.

Exemplo:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3);

gettype($array); // array
```

## Indução de Tipos

No PHP é possível "induzir tipos" específicos (não todos) para parâmetros passados em funções.

Podemos checar se um determinado objeto é de uma determinada instância ou subinstância. Se ele implementa uma interface, se é um callback, ou se é um array.

Exemplos de indução de tipo para classes:

```
class X{
   public function get(){}
}

function usa_x(X $x){
    return $x->get();
}

usa_x(new X);
```

Exemplos de indução de tipo para arrays:

```
function usa_array(array $array){
  foreach($array as $key => $value);
}

usa_array(1); // gera um erro!
```

Exemplos de indução de tipo para callbacks (a partir do php 5.4):

```
function usa_callback(callable $callback)
{
     return $callback(1, 2, 3);
}
usa_callback('var_dump');

usa_callback(function ($a, $b, $c){
   var_dump($a, $b, $c);
});

usa_callback('nao_existe'); // gera um erro
```

## SplType

Há uma extensão chamada `Spl Type`, onde é possível simular a definição de tipos através de instâncias de classes específicas para cada tipo.

Exemplo:

```
$int = new SplInt(94);

try {
    $int = 'Try to cast a string value for fun';
} catch (UnexpectedValueException $uve) {
    echo $uve->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

echo $int . PHP_EOL; // Value is not integer
```

Se  isso for necessário (creio que na maioria dos casos não é), aqui está o link para [SplType](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.spl-types.php)

Comment: Interessante... Outra coisa, esse array em PHP, é semelhante a struct do C? por que pelo que eu pesquisei, no array, podemos criar variáveis que são chamadas de "chaves" e atribuir valores para elas a partir da instancia do array, certo?

Comment: Sim. No PHP o `array` (atualmente -  como diz a documentação) é uma matriz ordenada. Não é simplesmente uma lista onde começa do 0 e vai até aonde você parar de adicionar elementos nessa lista!

Comment: O que eu pretendo fazer, é um conjunto de dados em um array, enviar esse array via socket para um programa em C, e esse programa C deve mover o bloco de memoria desse array para cima de uma struct que contem o mesmo conjunto de dados. Seria possivel? Se não, pq?

Comment: @Vynstus, nesse caso já muda muito o foco da pergunta. Sugiro que crie nova pergunta ou modifique a atual.

Comment: Eu criei, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76845/criando-buffers-em-php