# Criando buffers em PHP

Tags: php, c, socket

Pessoal preciso criar no PHP um *buffer* (string) de um conjunto de dados (array) para enviar via socket. Nesse *buffer* eu quero que todos os atributos do conjunto que são armazenados nele, obedeçam o seu tamanho.

Exemplo: Se vou armazenar um valor inteiro do conjunto de dados no *buffer*, ele terá que ocupar 4 bytes dentro desse *buffer*.

Código:

```
// Cria array
$bMsg3 = array (
    $at1 = 1,  
    $at2 = 2,
    $at3 = 3,
    $at4 = 4,
    $at5 = 5,
    $at6 = 6,
);

    $buffer[$at1]   = 32768;           /* Inteiro  = 4 bytes  */
    $buffer[$at2]   = 'HelloWorld';    /* String   = 10 bytes */
    $buffer[$at3]   = 123456;          /* Inteiro  = 4 bytes  */
    $buffer[$at4]   = 789101;          /* Inteiro  = 4 bytets */
    $buffer[$at5]   = 123852;          /* Float    = 4 bytes  */
    $buffer[$at6]   = 'teste';         /* String   = 5 bytes  */
                                      /* Total: 31 bytes     */

// Converte para string
$str = implode('', $buffer);

print "String: $str";
```

Nesse código, eu crio um *array* com vários atributos, e faço a conversão para string e armazeno na variável `$str`, dando um *print* no `$str`, fica assim:`132768HelloWorld123456789101123852teste`. Nesse caso o tamanho em bytes da string é de 39 bytes, enquanto deveria ser de 31 bytes, como eu poderia arrumar isso?

Comment: para ler um buffer com tamanho determinado você deverá usar [`fgets($handle, $tamanho_do_buffer)`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgets.php)

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.socket-read.php

Comment: Mas se você fizer a string ocupar 4 bytes ela vai perder informação porque cada letra representa 1 byte e em "stringTeste" tera 11 bytes

Comment: Note que at1 é um INTEGER e o at3 um FLOAT, ambos ocupam 4 bytes. at2 é uma string que ocupa 11 bytes. Entretando, convertendo isso para string, ela devera ter um total de 19 bytes, certo? A questão é, como converter o array para string, para que a string ocupe 19 bytes? que é o tamanho total dos atributos do array.

Comment: Como é que poderia ser 31 bytes? você tem mais 5 bytes de `:`, ou seja, `31+5 = 36`.

Comment: Acabei de colocar um exemplo melhor.

Comment: Mas se tu calculares os bytes de uma string, cada número conta como 1 caratere e não como um inteiro. `132768!='132768'`

Comment: Exatamente, Esse numero 132768 é um inteiro e é diferente de '132768' que é uma string. Por ser inteiro, ele ocupa 4 bytes, ou seja, qualquer numero inteiro ocupa 4 bytes.

Comment: exatamente, você disse tudo, convertendo tudo pra string será string. O que você pode fazer é talvez converter tudo para binário ou hexadecimal. Talvez definir uma estrutura de pacotes (package frame)

Comment: Tem ideia de como eu poderia converter em binario e colocar esses binarios na string? Pois eu preciso colocar esses dados dentro da string, com seus respectivos tamanhos.

Comment: da uma olhada na função pack do php

Comment: Quando o socket receber `"42Hello24"` como é que ele decide se recebeu um `int`, uma string e outro `int` ... ou 2 `int` (4, 2) 2 string ("hell", "o") e mais dois `int`??

Comment: @pmg Quando eu receber esta string no Programa em C, que tem uma struct contendo os mesmos atributos na sequencia, eu vou copior o bloco de memoria da string e jogar em cima da struct usando a função memmove(args). Por este motivo que eu quero que cada atributo respeite o tamanho do seu tipo na string.

Comment: @AdirKuhn não encontrei muita informação sobre a função pack, poderia descrever como ela funciona em uma resposta?

Comment: Porque não envias a string normal e depois tratas dela no C?

Comment: Daria muito mais trabalho do que a solução que estou procurando, e os processos no programa C devem ser menores, o tempo que o php demorar para criar a mensagem não é problema, no meu caso. Uma coisa pessoal, saberiam pq está imprimindo um numero 1 no inicio da string? sendo q ela começa no 32768.

Comment: @AdirKuhn Resolvi o problema usando a função Pack. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como já mencionei nos comentários a solução de utilizar string para montar o pacote é errada, pois se você converter um número para string ele será tratado como string pelo PHP então o int(40) que deveria ocupar 4 bytes na memória vai ocupar 2 bytes como string '4' e '0'

Você pode usar as funções pack / unpack do PHP para converter as informações em byte array. Ai os arrays terão os tamanhos que vc procura, mas mesmo assim pode ver que os elementos do array são **int**'s e se você juntar tudo também não será o resultado que você procura.

```
<?php

$bMsg3 = array (
    $at1 = 1,  
    $at2 = 2,
    $at3 = 3,
    $at4 = 4,
    $at5 = 5,
    $at6 = 6,
);

    $bMsg3[$at1]   = 32768;           /* Inteiro  = 4 bytes  */
    $bMsg3[$at2]   = 'HelloWorld';    /* String   = 10 bytes */
    $bMsg3[$at3]   = 123456;          /* Inteiro  = 4 bytes  */
    $bMsg3[$at4]   = 789101;          /* Inteiro  = 4 bytets */
    $bMsg3[$at5]   = 123852;          /* Float    = 4 bytes  */
    $bMsg3[$at6]   = 'teste';         /* String   = 5 bytes  */
                                      /* Total: 31 bytes     */

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(unpack("C*", pack("i", $bMsg3[$at1])));
var_dump(unpack("C*", $bMsg3[$at2]));
var_dump(unpack("C*", pack("i", $bMsg3[$at3])));
var_dump(unpack("C*", pack("i", $bMsg3[$at4])));
var_dump(unpack("C*", pack("i", $bMsg3[$at5])));
var_dump(unpack("C*", $bMsg3[$at6]));
```

Resultado:

```
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  int(0)
  [2]=>
  int(128)
  [3]=>
  int(0)
  [4]=>
  int(0)
}
array(10) {
  [1]=>
  int(72)
  [2]=>
  int(101)
  [3]=>
  int(108)
  [4]=>
  int(108)
  [5]=>
  int(111)
  [6]=>
  int(87)
  [7]=>
  int(111)
  [8]=>
  int(114)
  [9]=>
  int(108)
  [10]=>
  int(100)
}
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  int(64)
  [2]=>
  int(226)
  [3]=>
  int(1)
  [4]=>
  int(0)
}
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  int(109)
  [2]=>
  int(10)
  [3]=>
  int(12)
  [4]=>
  int(0)
}
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  int(204)
  [2]=>
  int(227)
  [3]=>
  int(1)
  [4]=>
  int(0)
}
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  int(116)
  [2]=>
  int(101)
  [3]=>
  int(115)
  [4]=>
  int(116)
  [5]=>
  int(101)
}
```

Então uma das possíveis soluções é converter tudo para hexa e enviar esse pacote na rede.

```
<?php

$bMsg3 = array (
    $at1 = 1,  
    $at2 = 2,
    $at3 = 3,
    $at4 = 4,
    $at5 = 5,
    $at6 = 6,
);

    $bMsg3[$at1]   = 32768;           /* Inteiro  = 4 bytes  */
    $bMsg3[$at2]   = 'HelloWorld';    /* String   = 10 bytes */
    $bMsg3[$at3]   = 123456;          /* Inteiro  = 4 bytes  */
    $bMsg3[$at4]   = 789101;          /* Inteiro  = 4 bytets */
    $bMsg3[$at5]   = 123852;          /* Float    = 4 bytes  */
    $bMsg3[$at6]   = 'teste';         /* String   = 5 bytes  */
                                      /* Total: 31 bytes     */

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(unpack("H*", pack("i", $bMsg3[$at1])));
var_dump(unpack("H*", $bMsg3[$at2]));
var_dump(unpack("H*", pack("i", $bMsg3[$at3])));
var_dump(unpack("H*", pack("i", $bMsg3[$at4])));
var_dump(unpack("H*", pack("i", $bMsg3[$at5])));
var_dump(unpack("H*", $bMsg3[$at6]));
```

Que vai resultar nisso, mas para enviar tu pode juntar todos numa única string.

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(8) "00800000"
}
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(20) "48656c6c6f576f726c64"
}
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(8) "40e20100"
}
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(8) "6d0a0c00"
}
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(8) "cce30100"
}
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(10) "7465737465"
}
```

No C o pacote vem como um unsigned char, então podemos ter esse exemplo aqui para imprimir os dados. (usando um pequeno pedaço do pacote)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void) {

    unsigned char pacote[] = { 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x57, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64 };

    struct pckt {
        int a;
        char b[10];
    };


    struct pckt *meu_pckt = (struct pckt*) pacote;
    char n[11];
    memcpy(n, meu_pckt->b, 10);
    n[10] = '\0';
    printf("%d\n", meu_pckt->a);
    printf("%s\n", n);

    return 0;   
}
```

Deve imprimir:

```
32768
HelloWorld
```

Comment: Aqui estou usando os formatos i e f, para inteiros e floats na função pack(format,args...), e funcionou perfeitamente. O unico problema é que não encontrei formato para as Strings, você sabe me dizer? Segue a linha de comando:  $str  = pack("iiifa", $atributo1, $atributo2, $atributo3, $atributo4, $atributo5); OBS: o ultimo formato 'a' pega somente o primeiro caracter da string.

Comment: string nada mais é que caracteres representados por um número da tabela ascii. Eu optaria por utilizar H* pois fica mais fácil de trabalhar no C

Comment: quando eu coloco H* da este erro: http://pastebin.com/fYpTdfG8

Comment: unpack("H*", .....);

Comment: usei a* e deu certo, obrigado :D

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é uma boa solução, mas isso deve funcionar.

```
    $array = array(
        (int)substr($str, 0, 4),
        substr($str, 4, 10),
        (int)substr($str, 10, 4),
        (int)substr($str, 14, 4),
        (float)substr($str, 18, 4),
        substr($str, 22, 5),            
    );
```

Comment: O que isso está fazendo?

Comment: Ele esta convertendo alguns valores para inteiro (`(int)`) e garantindo o tamanho da variável `$str` utilizando o `substr` definindo a posição inicial e a final.